# Repeating Background image getting cut off

Tags: html, css

I have a container DIV which scales with it's content in height. It has a background image that repeats down making a pattern.

The Problem is the repeating background image gets cut off at the bottom of the div.

**Is there a way to tell the background image to not get cut off?**

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/WkEKD/7/

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide us some code or [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: That depends on your div's height and your background image. One possible solution may is to assign background image property on page load. But I don't think, It will work for you.

Comment: I have Looked at the css3 background-repeat:round; property but it does not yet support all newer browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the height (computed if height is auto) of your div is not a multiple of the height of your background image, it will get cut off (`overflow: visible` does not apply to background images). Two possible solutions are:

1. Make sure your height of your DIV is a multiple of the height of your background-image
2. Use the `background-size` property (CSS3 only) to scale the background image to fill the DIV (if applicable)
3. Use a little bit of JS to set the height of your DIV to the nearest multiple of the height of your background image (i.e. basically same as 1, but via JS)

**Code for Option #3**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h6tUs/2/

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    adjustHeight(img.height);
};
img.src = 'http://www.jamfactory.co.za/left.png';
if(img.complete) {
    adjustHeight(img.height);
}
function adjustHeight(_imgHeight) {
    var ht = $('#container').outerHeight(false);
    ht = ht + (ht % _imgHeight);
    $('#container').height(ht);    
}
```

The above code should go inside your `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: Number 3 would sound like the right answer. But i don't know where in the world to find such solution. :) Is it possible to add a link to a example or tutorial to accomplish this? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Is this all really needed? Check my answer

Comment: The answer provided by Dipaks is in fact more elegant and avoids the need for any JS. One minor downside is that you wont be able to use huge font sizes in your DIV For ex: if you need your div to have a font-size of 36px or so, it may not be visually appealing.

Answer (score 1):

One line solution to this problem could be setting line height same as the background image height that is `line-height: 20px;`

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/WkEKD/10/

```
#container {
margin:0 auto;
width:20px;
background:url('http://www.jamfactory.co.za/left.png') 0 0;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your div's content is exclusively text, maybe you could tweak the line-height parameter in css to some fraction of the height of your tiled background image?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible solutions for your problem.

As Tom C said you could just change the line height to match the height of your background.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nr2ca/1/

A better solution would be to make each line a sub element and apply the background to each of these. (If you are making a navigation use an unordered list)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get your desired result through simple `CSS` like mentioning below :-

**CSS**

```
body {background-color:#000}
#container {
margin:0 auto;
width:20px;
background:url('http://www.jamfactory.co.za/left.png') repeat-y 0 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
    <p><br/></p>
</div>
```

you should always define the `background-repeat` value for how do you want to repeat the image like on `x-axis` or `y-axis`. If you will define these values i hope image will repeat perfectly as per your requirements.

see the demo : - http://tinkerbin.com/1kg6u3PW