# How to repeat background image as a block

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to repeat a background image as a block? When I make the div 100% width and set the height to 70px this image repeats well but the problem is depending on the width of the box, sometimes half of the item shows up and that doesn't make any sense. I want whole image to repeat if there's space if not repeat should end. Is it possible?

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
  position: relative;
  padding: 55px 0 0 0;
}
#notepadTop {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/lbW0QX6.png') repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="notepadTop">

  </div>
</div>
```

This is the image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npfpv.png]

Comment: Similar to this question but with width: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390646/repeating-background-image-getting-cut-off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in your css:

`background-repeat: round`

so, you have:

```
#notepadTop {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -24px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/lbW0QX6.png');
  background-repeat: round;
}
```

the value `round` is a new CSS3 option so this won't work on IE8 and below (you shouldn't be worry about it).

Comment: Didn't really help :/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you are looking for `background-size: cover;`

Comment: i dont think so it will work , background-size:cover will starch one image to whole div

Comment: I want background to repeat but as a block so I don't want it to repeat 2 and a half times, if there's space it should repeat 3 times if not 2 times.