# How to prevent background repeat image from cutting off

Tags: css, background-image

Is there a way to prevent css from cutting off a background image using background repeat?
`background-repeat: repeat-x;` repeats the image side by side until the space runs out, and cuts the image where the div finishes. Is there a way to space the images between instead? like a sort of `justify-content: space-between;` but for background images?

**current result**

[image]

**expected result**

[image]

I know I can use images and use display flex, but this would mess with the layout. I also read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390646/repeating-background-image-getting-cut-off) where it shows how to do it with js but I think this is not worth it as I'd have to listen to the resize event to make it responsive. Is there a way to do it with just css?

```css
#container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/100/100');
  border: black solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use background-repeat: space;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

```css
#container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/100/100');
  border: black solid 3px;
  background-repeat: space;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that was fast, thank you!